# Want a more distinctive horizontal rule

Tags: feature-request, markdown, design

The [horizontal rule](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#horizontal-rules) that we are permitted to use within a question should be more visibly different from the lines that break multiple answers, and the answer from the comments.

The line that breaks the answer from the comments seems to be the same width and a very similar color as that line that can be used inside an answer.  It would be nice if this was different,  perhaps it could have a different width, perhaps that didn't spawn the entire answer box width?

The green arrow in the attached image is my suggestion about how you might adjust the formatting of an HR in a answer/question.

[image: hr rule formatting]

(click image for full size)

Comment: You made it much harder to see; I looked at the green arrow and wondered what you were pointing at